# Module name "crypto" has not been loaded yet for context

Tags: javascript

While trying to use [this library](https://gist.github.com/yoavniran/c78a0991e0152b306c25) 
I initially got error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.
To solve it, I added [required library](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html). This now started with another error as `Module name "crypto" has not been loaded yet for context`

FOR LEG PULLERS: This is not a duplicate question, As all the questions are either poorly answered or not answered. 
I have done my research, EG: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311278/884674) does not tells where to try it.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626192/karma-webpack-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-context-use-require) is unanswered. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448869/884674) does not tells where do I get those paths like 'path/to/filesize' and all other paths anyways if I get then also is useless in my context. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448839/884674) defines a module of its own, I need a predefined "crypto" module. The default [google library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) is not doing the job.

Comment: You don't need requirejs library, because nodejs has its own require function. You need to figure out why `require is not defined`. Are you trying with node or browser? If second - script by link simply not for this case.

Comment: Quick follow up. What's the environment? Node/browser? Version?

Comment: I am doing it with JQM. In Firefox-WebIde

Answer (score 2):

From my guessing, you are under browser environment instead of developing a NodeJS app.

This [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) you refer to is actually for back-end (NodeJS), provided as NodeJS API, and also, the `require` keyword, is a NodeJS one.

And from my knowledge, there is no `crypto` in the default browser environment, neither is there a `require`. For most cases, there is a [REQUIRE.JS](http://requirejs.org/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) that let you use this type of `require` statement, but for your case, I suggest not to use them.

For crypto used in browser environment, I would suggest something using some third-party libraries, like [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js), and you without browserify or bower, you should pay special attention to its [Usage without RequireJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js#usage-without-requirejs) section.